# Can I password protect a location (not directory) in apache using htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, authentication, htpasswd

I have used code like this in apache configuration to protect locations with password

```
<Location ~ "/admin.*">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Protected Area"
    AuthUserFile /home/user/public_html/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

is there a way to do the same thing using an htaccess file?

the locations I want to protect don't really exist on the filesystem, it's locations available thanks to mod_rewrite

Answer (score 3):

Yep, with `<Files>` (or `<FilesMatch>`): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files

Edit: "Note that unlike Directory and Location sections, Files sections can be used inside .htaccess files. This allows users to control access to their own files, at a file-by-file level."

Comment: I'm not sure this does what dimvic is looking for -- A <Location> directive can point to something that's not on the filesystem (e.g. `<Location /server-status>`) in which case .htaccess wouldn't work.  It's probably viable if the area to be protect "really exists" though...

Comment: I suspect they are files.

Comment: the area doesn't really exist, this is the problem, i need to protect an area that exists thanks to mod_rewrite

Comment: If the area doesn't exist (on the filesystem) then there is no place to put an .htaccess file so what you are asking is impossible.

Comment: I was thinking that it could possibly be done with an htaccess placed in the site's root folder

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to do so put a htaccess in the file you want to moderate the access. Put the same text as in the configuration file. Make sure that your conf files will read .htaccess.

Comment: I meant add it to one of directory that you need to moderate.

Comment: <Location> tags are not accepted in htaccess, it's context is "server config, virtual host" http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location